# Scala Spark: flatMap does not accept function that returns Option

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, flatmap

I'm trying to apply an optional transformation (`parseRow`) to a `Dataset` with `flatMap`, so that `None`s are discarded and `Some`s are unwrapped.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object Main
{
    def parseRow(line: String): Option[Map[String, String]] = Some(Map())

    def main(args: Array[String])
    {
        val ss = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

        ss.read.textFile("somewhere")
          .flatMap(parseRow _)
          .write.parquet("somewhere/else")
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I got the following error:

```
[error] Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset.  Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes) are supported by importing spark.implicits._  Support for serializing other types will be added in future releases.
[error]           .flatMap(parseRow _)
[error]                   ^
```

I tried the fix suggested in the error, i.e. I added `import ss.implicits._`, but it didn't change anything.

I think I might be in a situation similar to the one described [here](https://dev.sortable.com/flatmap-to-option/) (i.e. for some reason the implicit conversion from `Option` to `TraversableOnce` is not being applied), but I'm not good enough in Scala to find a solution for my case.

I tried to change that line to `.flatMap(line => parseRow(line))` or `.flatMap(parseRow)`, but it didn't work.